# Am I in a review ban? Or are the reviews down?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

Unlike a lot of users I actually like reviewing and do it quite often. I would consider myself to be a good reviewer as I have never failed a review audit. My comments left for the posters have nearly always gone to the user improving their post and I have left lots of helpful flags.

I just came back on the Stack Overflow after a couple of hours break and when I press on the review icon it says "There are no available review queues to you"

[image]

I have no idea why this could be as I thought my reviews were helpful to this site. Has the reputation required changed or are the reviews down? Or worst case, have I been banned from reviewing? And if so, why doesn't it tell me I have been banned?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Can you middle-button-click on that menu? That should ideally take you to the /review page where you can see if you're banned or not.

Comment: Or, if middle click isn't available to you, right click on the icon and select open in new tab (or similar)

Answer (score 59):

You were manually banned from review by a moderator for 7 days due to [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16549487):

[image]

(you approved pretty clear spam).

You would have seen that ban notice had you gone to the review queues themselves, but there isn't the room to show that in the review dropdown.

Comment: looking back at it yes i probably picked the wrong option, but a ban notification would be nice to get instead of just not letting me access the page and guess

Comment: Tricky when the menu options that *lead* you to the review queues aren't available. It might be nice if that message had a "Why?" link at the end, leading to the review ban notice or something else that would clarify things.

Comment: @PaulRoub: I've made 
 a follow up feature request to make this more obvious; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned

Comment: dat question tho

Comment: "pretty clear spam" is debatable, except for very loose definitions of "spam". That answer may or may not be soliciting (sounds like they probably are, but maybe they thought they were just providing a starting point; who knows, it's really bad english), but it most certainly isn't a non-contextual redirection, let alone a generic or automated one. Whether the answer should be hosed down as a bad answer is one thing, but punishing a reviewer for "failing to clear obvious spam" when in this particular case the obviousness of the spam is debatable and subjective seems like abuse of power to me.

Comment: Not to mention, given how bad and broad the _question_ is, that answer (quality of english aside) could well be construed as a pretty reasonable answer. Basically it says "it's possible, but not trivial, so I wouldn't just start hacking something together if you're trying to make a profitable business out of it. Here, check this tool that automates some of your task to see how one might go about it to begin with".

Comment: It's surprising that the thread in question has not been deleted yet. Spent a delete vote.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I disagree with "abuse of power" but yeah, I don't think it's as clear-cut spam as it's claimed to be.

Comment: @JanDvorak well, a degree of it, for sure. (I ran out of characters to be more gentle). But, yes, fair enough, I didn't picture it as an evil cackling PHB in my head or anything; it was more along the lines of being a bit more trigger-happy than the situation warranted.

Comment: Programming takes "efforts, patience and high skills".  I did not know that.

Comment: To make it more clear, I would suggest to replace "There are no review queues available to you" by something like "You are banned because of [this review](http://example.com), come back in X hours/days to continue reviewing" with a link to the review that caused the ban. **Edit:** I just noticed that there is already a feature request suggesting this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351386/4284627

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Regardless of whether it was clearly spam or not, choosing "No action needed" was the incorrect choice given the fact that content was not really understandable - either and attempt to edit or skipping if the reviewer is not willing to improve the quality would be more appropriate, at the very least.

Comment: Okay, I genuinely can't understand why anyone thinks it isn't obvious that this is spam. An answer to what I can already tell is an off-topic question, which uses poor grammar and repeatedly mentions "business", says nothing about programming beyond *trying to dissuade the OP from doing any*; then drops a link in the middle of a paragraph and suggests that people go there to "directly download the ready made script or website or apps"? What more do you need???

Answer (score -8):

You can also check it by manually going to one of your review pages, like to https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts

So you will see, if you are really in ban or not. If you are on ban, you will see if some wonderful mod wants the site rather unreviewed than reviewed by you; and how does he reason.

Comment: "If you are on ban, you will see if some wonderful mod wants the site rather unreviewed than reviewed by you" If they're doing incorrect reviews, that seems like the desirable outcome to me. No reviewing is better than bad reviewing.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yeah. Somewhere I've read, the mods focus to the users, who failed the most review audits. (The count of the *passed* audits does not matter.) I tried to argument, that instead the ratio of the passed/failed audits should matter (== the probability that the user fails an audit), it was not even reacted.