# Make it more obvious that you're review banned

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, top-bar, review-suspension

[This recent post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351377/am-i-in-a-review-ban-or-are-the-reviews-down) revealed how non-obvious it is to a user that they're review banned;

[image]

It seems that in order to determine whether you're review banned or not you either have to;

1. *Manually* navigate to `/review` in your browser.
2. *Middle* click on the "Review" icon in the header.

... neither of which are obvious.

Can we make it more obvious to the user that they're review banned? Some suggestions;

1. When review banned, left clicking on "Review" icon goes to `/review` (which shows the user they're banned, how long for, and for what reason).
2. When review banned, left clicking on "Review" the popup (shown above) includes details on the review ban
3. Leave all of the links to the queues there, just like normal, and show the user the ban message when they navigate to a queue (thanks, [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy))

A key part of banning a user from review is the *education* that comes in the suspension message. Currently, not only is it confusing as to *whether* a user is banned or not, but we're also making it *extremely* hard for them to learn from their suspension.

Comment: You don't even need to change the drop down at all from the non-banned behavior.  Just leave all of the links to the queues there, just like normal, and show the user the ban message when they navigate to a queue.

Comment: leaving the links to queues there wouldn't be consistent with normal way when system hides queues that aren't available ATM (eg close queue is hidden after I did 40 reviews, LA/FP are hidden when I'm out of votes ets). However there is link ["All Queues"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFOjs.png) in the drop down that could be kept for suspended users

Comment: Ironically [most of SO thinks they're review banned right now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link)

Comment: Or it could be that users boycott reviews because they are sick of the broken review audits.

Comment: Only for Note :- You also don't get the notification when your are banned from the edit. Just edit button is disabled but there isn't any notification.

Comment: Middle click? The hell?

Comment: @canon Middle-clicking a link opens it in a new tab (and in this case, also bypasses the JavaScript that intercepts left clicks and opens the dropdown in response).

Comment: @Servy Ideally, I'd rather not have to navigate to another page to find out I was banned.

Comment: @NathanArthur Why not?

Comment: @Servy I'm lazy.

Comment: @NathanArthur Do you find yourself review banned so frequently that a single click every time it happens is really *that* burdensome.

Comment: @Servy No, I don't. (I don't spend much time in review queues.) My point is, when designing an interface, I try to tell the user they can't do something early. I view every step a user takes towards an unreachable goal as reflecting poorly on my design.

Comment: @NathanArthur Sure, and that's the basis for the current behavior, but *it doesn't work in this situation*.  Normally you can simply hide the fact that a user can't do something, because they don't need to know what they can't do, or why.  Here, there needs to be an explanation that not only are they banned, but why, and what to do as a result, information not particularly well suited to being shown in place.

Comment: @Servy That's fair. So why not something like [this](https://snag.gy/3Qqlo9.jpg)?

Comment: @NathanArthur Because you're effectively forcing the user to click through and go to the other page anyway (as that message is lacking so much in information they're going to need to click through to see the full message anyway), so you're not actually saving them a click by showing them that message instead of just doing nothing and letting them go to the review queue and see the ban message.

Answer (score 144):

I've always found it odd that there's not a notification for a review ban. I mean, I get one for a whole host of reasons but SO's position seems to be

> Surprise! You're review banned!

Just send a notice. It pops up in something most people actively use anyways and it would be useful because you could see the reason *right there*.

[image]

Comment: can we also flag the moderator message in this popup?, or do I need to do another FR for that?

Comment: for a moment there I thought you were really banned.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Gotta love consoles and their editing of loaded HTML :)

Comment: What irks me most is the comma that doesn't belong between 'reading' and 'disturbing'.

Comment: @TylerH Feels poetic though. I appreciate the mental pause.

Answer (score 18):

The review dropdown now let's the review suspended user know about their review suspension, and directs them to the `/review` page where a more detailed notice is available. Read about our [new improved experience for users with review suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351118/51) for more info.

[image: Screenshot of the topbar review dropdown messaging during and after a review suspension is in effect]

---

> review suspension:
> used to be confusing, no?
> now see the notice

Comment: I got a ban once - I cannot remember when - System, please tell me.