# Is there a way to know if I am in review ban and when it will end?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

In top bar, Review Queues icon is orange initially. But when I click it, it does not load queue list.

[image]

This might be due to I am banned for review. But I do not remember the message prompted by Stack Overflow saying I am banned.

Is there a way to know if this is true and when the ban will end?

Comment: This may help: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned

Comment: Maybe go to a review queue directly. Close Votes is always full, so that should be a good test. **If** you are review banned (I'm not saying you are), your first concern should be why, not when the ban is over.

Comment: You are indeed banned from review: *You reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17227126 incorrectly. This was an answer to the question asked: the question was how to check if a memory address is valid, and the answer was a macro that does precisely this. Yes, it was a link, but it was not a link-only answer. The answer explained the purpose of the function, and the link text was itself the answer. The link was merely supplemental, to the source code itself. This should not have been deleted.* The ban ends tomorrow.

Comment: The dropdown being empty is very unhelpful here; I've duped this to the feature request to make this clearer.

Comment: You should have seen that message Martijn quoted *somewhere*, otherwise the manual review-ban system is completely broken. The review-ban messages are supposed to be educational. Review bans are not generally meant to be punitive. If you can't read the message, you can't learn from your mistakes, and thus you will never improve. It was a very short ban; I can't understand how you might have already forgotten what the message said.

Comment: @CodyGray: The answer was not an audit. May be Moderator re-reviewed my review latter some time and banned me. I am sure I never seen that message _while reviewing_; until today when I manually opened `\review` page.

Comment: Failing audits is not the only way to get a review ban. Moderators can impose a review ban manually. They do this if they feel a user is reviewing badly. I suggest you have a look at the [review guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/168333), and see if you can improve your reviewing. Otherwise, you risk being review banned again, for a longer time.

Comment: Right, it was a manual ban issued by a moderator, not an audit. I check over reviewers' actions when I process flags. This was a case where the answer was deleted by reviewers, and then undeleted by the person who originally posted it. We get an auto-flag in these cases, and generally it's so we can step in and force a deletion. In this case, I felt it was pretty clear that the answer *was* an answer; the reviewers just triggered on "short answer+link", concluding it was "link-only" when it wasn't. As stated, the ban wasn't meant to be punitive--just educational. If you have questions, ask.