# Can moderator responses to flags show up in the notification inbox?

Tags: feature-request, flags, notifications

Could we get responses to moderator flags in our "Recent inbox messages"?

Let me explain why. I've had an experience with a user I've been constantly flagging for the same question asked, and I missed the message from the moderator "Keep flagging them as they appear. We're working to expand the IP ban here."

I did that (more or less), but I would have done more if I had noticed and read that message.

Comment: Do you mean the Stack Overflow notification system?  Or do you mean emails being sent to the email you registered with?

Comment: @ryanyuyu, the "inbox icon" on SO.

Comment: Only for custom mod flags which are not handled with a stock comment I may hope?

Comment: @rene, I don't know what you mean. I've flagged a post for "in need of moderator intervention" and received an accepted moderator flag with an answer that I was not notified about. That's the point. I would like to get a notification about that. And I believe many "flaggers" might appreciate that. I mean, I would like to get the moderator response to my flag indicated in my account.

Comment: @Victoria you can periodically check your [flag summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/8041231) - I think there's even a user script that does that for you. The criteria of what should be inbox'd would need to be carefully chosen though - there's people that use 100 flags a day and mods tend to handle things in batches - so it'd be a lot of noise all at once potentially...

Comment: @Jon, well, I realized what to do now. But the others? Besides. in this particular case many people voted down, close, flag and whatsoever but if I were notified about a >>MODERATOR<< message, I would act accordingly. I was not, and that's the point of this feature request.

Comment: @Victoria on a good day I might raise 100 flags, 99% of those are expected to be *helpful* as the response. Even on most of my custom mod flags I simply get *helpful* back. I don't want that in my inbox. That is why I think your feature request should be limited to the custom mod flag that are handled by a moderator where the moderator left a custom message. In its current form I don't fancy your FR, I would like to opt out.

Comment: @rene, well what about some "moderator inbox" then?

Comment: I keep an eye on my flag page if I know I have pending flags. So that is my *moderator inbox*. And I do run into a mod now and then in a  chat room I frequent....

Comment: Flags were originally meant to be fire and forget and only marked helpful if they were reasonable things to raise or declined if used incorrectly. I could see an argument for notifying users somehow of the status of processed *custom flags* where a moderator has chosen to reply with a *custom reason* otherwise it'd just be so much noise for the majority of users. The thing is, the committed flaggers will check their flag summary page and of the remainder of the community that uses them - I doubt they really care about updates as long as something happens if necessary - they flag and move on.

Comment: @JonClements do you have stats on how often mods use a custom reason?

Comment: I think there could be some merit in declined flags notifications, if only for educational purposes.

Comment: @Jon, that's what I mean. Say to the user, you did it well, or no if necessary to react, but notify that somehow.

Comment: @rene, how could I know what's wrong when I flag some posts whithout checking my "flags" page and it's declined (or accepted with a further comment)?

Comment: @rene I don't. I think Shog published some stats a while back of how many custom flags are raised but I don't believe a breakdown of result let alone the reason used was included. (From experience - I'm going to guess a lot of were just helpful or declined with "please use standard flags...")

Comment: @Victoria you couldn't. That is why you started this FR, right?

Comment: @Victoria to make this FR more clear can you please state why the flag-summary page is not enough and on what type flags you like inbox notification. There is a lot of people like rene that raise tons of flag everyday as for example [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy?tab=topactivity), will he get 130,586 notifications in inbox?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned