# Do I get a notification for a review ban?

Tags: support, review-suspension

I got my first (automatic) 2-day review ban today for failing an audit with an actually [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19449214) review, since I said a spam answer was looking OK.  I agree the ban was deserved and the review did not reflect my best work, so to speak.

If you are interested in the "mechanics" of my failed audit, for some reason I thought the answer was coming from the owner of the API the question was about.

The thing is that I didn't notice I was banned, since I guess I stopped reviewing after failing the audit; a few hours later I checked the review queues and it just said "there are no review queues available to you".

Then I edited the URL to "https://stackoverflow.com/review" and saw the ban message.

Did I miss any ban message? Or is this the way things are supposed to be, i.e. just the "no review queues available" message?

Comment: You lost a message like this one:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158675/why-am-i-getting-the-message-youve-failed-too-many-recent-review-audits

Comment: Related: [Make it more obvious that you're review banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned/351409). If not altogether duplicate.

Comment: You would have gotten the notice immediately after failing that audit I believe. Apart from that - the dupe applies.

Comment: Well I'm not complaining that the ban isn't obvious enough, I've seen posts where people were saying they felt "bad" because of the way bans are notified, so I thought "semi-hiding" the ban could be a policy or something not to "hurt" people. Also, perhaps I didn't see the notice because I closed the window after being notified the failed audit, so perhaps the window I missed would've shown if I had clicked "Next" or something...

Answer (score 15):

When you asked this question, the answer was "no". [As of today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions), we've made it more obvious when you're suspended from review by adding a more informative notice at the top of the review queue that links to a longer explanation of your suspension. Additionally, users who were previously review suspended but returned after their suspension ended will be shown the same suspension message so that they're aware that they had been suspended previously.

We still rely on the review queue indicator being active to draw attention to it rather than sending a notification to your inbox about the review suspension. This is something we may add in the future but we're going to see how things work out without the notification.