# Retain a link in the top bar review queue menu for users in review suspension

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, user-interface, review-suspension

**Expected behavior**:

When a user clicks the review queue icon on the top bar, the drop down menu includes a link to https://stackoverflow.com/review (link text: "all queues").

**Actual behavior**:

When a user is in review suspension, that link disappears along with the list of queues.

**Why I believe it's a problem**:

This seems undesirable because that URL will contain information explaining the review suspension.

Without that link there is no obvious way for users to navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/review <sup>1</sup>. This leads to confusion because it is unclear why the UI has suddenly changed.

If a user is unable to reach that page, they will not be able to read the suspension message. I would guess that a non-trivial number of users end up waiting out the suspension without even realizing what has happened. The process ends up being ineffective.

**Request**: change the UI for users under review suspension so that the link to https://stackoverflow.com/review is still available in the review queue menu on the top bar.

**Note**: I found this request: [Make it more obvious that you're review banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned). I am opening this one because while the linked request proposes several solutions, the one I am suggesting is not among them. That one is also 2.5 years old.

---

<sub>1: there might be other links on the site but none are as obvious as the one in the top bar, and that is almost certainly the one that is most frequently used. I can't actually find another link but I didn't try that hard. (Middle-click or "open in new window/tab" work, but that is hidden functionality (I don't even have a middle mouse button))</sub>

Comment: I support this request. Without making it obvious to users that they are review-banned, they are just going to keep reviewing incorrectly without knowing what went wrong, and I'm just going to keep doubling the suspension periods to [make a point](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/a/2509/48).

Comment: @SamuelLiew I agree with this as my last suspension was 7 days after I marked a triage as requires editing thinking it meant OP could fix the question just by adding some details. All my ban showed, after I finally got to the page mostly by luck, was that I had said requires editing and all 3 others said un-salvageable. I'm currently banned for 16 days for making the same mistake but this time I know, only because the two other people also said requires editing and so the message was different and explained the difference as well as linking https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148

Comment: Marking this [meta-tag:status-completed] per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399709/16481332); ping if incorrect triage

Answer (score 7):

It looks like this is going to be implemented, see [this Meta Stack Exchange announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346903/295232):

> [image]
>
> In the event of a suspension, a user will be notified in the Review Queue dropdown. A post notification will be available with reason and time remaining on the Review Queue main page, along with guidance for continued learning in this area. We’re also proposing softening the language by renaming “review bans” to “review suspensions.”

As for the timeline:

> As a reminder, this project is still in the [**early stages of discovery**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346894/new-feedback-tag-product-discovery). In this post, we are sharing proposed changes to review bans and other new features. We are asking for your feedback before we begin implementation. After we collect community feedback, we will be open to including changes into the next design iteration.

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346902/295232))