# review-needed indicator should not show up when banned?

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-suspension

I got banned from the review queue for tagging wrong. [First I didn't realise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned), but that's not the point of this suggestion.

Now I get the red dot prompting to action(?) and when clicking it says "There are no review queues available to you". So maybe remove red dot if I'm banned.