# Are superfluous comments in an answer (such as "good luck") discouraged?

Tags: discussion, edits

One of my accepted answers was edited by a much more experienced SO member to remove a comment I made at the end of my answer to the poster of the original question:

> "Good luck and happy coding."

I am unsure as to why such a comment may be removed. While I realise a message to the OP (such as the one edited out) is superfluous in the context of the answer, going through the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), I could not find any reference discouraging something like that. It seems like a polite thing to do (just as saying thank you at the end of a question is polite) and something that would encourage and bring good feeling in a community.

In any case, I'm just looking for some clarity, since this is something I have been doing in many of my answers.

Should I stop adding such comments to the end of my answers and edit my previous posts accordingly?

Comment: Very related [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)

Comment: Also related: [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions) It talkes about questions, but the general idea is the same for answers.

Comment: Quote: "Keep going and keep asking questions!"  Worst kind of fluff, makes no sense to the next thousand programmers that google your answer.  SO is not a forum.

Comment: Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) is like an encyclopedia for everyone (e.g. Wikipedia) build upon many Q&A. So, a similar situation will be like reading "Good luck and happy researching." at the end of a wiki article.

Comment: @hans Fair enough. But it seems very likely the majority of programmers looking at that question are new to programming and would perhaps appreciate such encouragement. But, as you say, SO is not a forum. So, I understand that.

Comment: I just feel a need to point out again that I am new to SO (which was edited out) and I had no knowledge of this kind of language being discouraged. It is not mentioned in the FAQs. I was genuinely trying to create really great, well thought out answers (and at the time, I assumed encouragement was a good thing for that). I am a teacher by day and thus, attempting to be encouraging is something I do by nature. It is disheartening to feel like you did the wrong thing when you made a tremendous effort with something. I appreciate those here for being diplomatic and kind in their answers.

Comment: The canonical is *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950)* (cross site).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Should I stop adding such comments to the end of my answers and edit my previous posts accordingly?

Yes, please. It is what we call *noise*, *a distraction*, *frivolity* and we try to focus only on valuable content. Much more like Wikipedia and less so like traditional forums.

Posts should be free of *meta* information. So that visitors only have to consume actual content that addresses their problem.

Comment: It's not always 100% fluff.  It can mean 'OK, ignore my comment/answer and carry on with your current design.  You will need a lot of luck, because I'm confident you are heading to disaster'.  I agree that such encoded idioms are not clear, especially to ESL users and, as such sbould be avoided.

Comment: If users feel compelled to say it, it can be added to comments (where it is mostly harmless).

Comment: @PeterMortensen you are effectively advising people to use comments for what they are not intended there. If I feel compelled to spew profanity, I should shout into a pillow. If someone is compelled to write fluff, they should write a poem. All of that really has no place on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It feels a little strange to compare fluff (which in the context of this question, is saying thanks, good luck - ie, kindness and courtesy) with spewing profanity. For someone like myself who thought they were just doing the decent thing (and who is new and doesn't know all the rules and the associated nuances) it feels intimidating to hear such things as "you should go write a poem". Again, I understand the reasons and why one might say such a thing, but I can think of worse things in this world than someone saying thanks (oh, the horror!) or good luck.

Comment: @Gimby Well, I think you're going to have to start flagging the post from staff then: [Make it more obvious that you're review banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399709/12695027). I also do not agree that poems aren't good Answers. If they're to the point and actually answers the Question, they're good.

Comment: @MichaelLundie It's not the same at all. I do not agree with the comparison. "Thanks" and the likes are just removed, while profanities can result in penalties. There are differences between main and meta, with much more leeway on meta. One funny result was [A Yaakov Ellis-inspired Meta.SE poetry contest: Write poems, win rep!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349555/a-yaakov-ellis-inspired-meta-se-poetry-contest-write-poems-win-rep). Kindly note that it was only to be applied to meta sites :)

Comment: @MichaelLundie We are pretty bad at setting expectations. What helps me when writing a post here is to think about the audience. I'm writing for the many visitors to come. I can't know or anticipate if those users need to be thanked (*Hey! Thanks for having the same problem as I have*) or need encouragement. In the early design stages it was considered to leave out users at all from posts, to just focus on content. Yes, that is different from forums and reddit and twitter but this site and its Q&A model **is** different. I think it is essential to value and embrace that difference.  YMMV.