# Why do I see "There are no review queues" message? Am I review-banned?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-suspension

I am currently seeing the "there are no review queues for you" message. I know this shows when you fumble audits, but I haven't even been reviewing recently.

Am I banned? I never received any message regarding this. If I made a mistake, how can I check what it was?

Comment: Yes - you are banned. I know because I am currently banned too and have the same experience. You can get more information (why and for how long) by going to https://stackoverflow.com/review - you'll get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgEWt.png).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I in a review ban? Or are the reviews down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351377/am-i-in-a-review-ban-or-are-the-reviews-down)

Answer (score 26):

Yeah, you're review-banned. You should see a message to that effect *somewhere*.

I can't believe [they still haven't fixed the UI to make review bans more obvious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned). If you're banned and you *don't know it*, then that's a serious problem. A very important purpose of bans is to allow reviewers to learn from their mistakes.

The ban relates to your decision on [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24308910). See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380508/is-there-an-appeal-process-for-review-queue-access-suspension/380522#380522) for context. In summary, when I handle flags on obvious not-an-answer or very-low-quality posts, I check to see if any reviewers failed to reach that same conclusion. If they do, I give out bans as door prizes, following the same gradually incrementing time periods as the automatic (audit-based) bans.

Comment: I really thought at the first look that it was a new answer (similar to another answer but without the `**`). One should have edited the question though to format code as code and at that point it should have been clear.

Comment: @BDL Well, it *does* look like a new answer at first glance. The only way to tell it's not is to click through to the question and see that the quote comes from an existing answer. By handing out review bans for people who got this wrong, Cody effectively makes that level of diligence the minimum acceptable standard for anyone reviewing answers with quotes in them. That will displease some people, to be sure - a significant subset of users think it's unreasonable to be expected to look at anything beyond what the review system puts in front of their nose when reviewing. I support it, though.

Comment: @MarkAmery: My point is that even when seeing both answers, they seem to not have the same code included. One has `**` while the other hasn't. But this is because the copy doesn't put the code in a code block and thus `**` disappears and makes the text bold.

Comment: @BDL An understandable mistake - but still one that reviewers in the Late Answers queue ideally wouldn't be making. Newbies unfamiliar with markdown inadvertently garbling formatting is really common - e.g. anyone who frequents the Python tag has probably seen the `__init__` method rendered __init__ a painful number of times - and one of the things that I'd hope the First Posts and Late Answers reviewers would spot and fix for us. (There's also a full phrase of English copied that ought to be a clue about what's going on, even for someone caught out by the code formatting mismatch.)

Comment: @MarkAmery: I completely agree with the ban. It was really just meant as a remark for the reviewer onto why the two answers are the same.

Comment: May we have screen of the answer, as educational material? Clicking the link gave me "Answer  answer not found"

Comment: @xdtTransform https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPEgf.png

Comment: That's a tough review to ban someone for. You can't tell that it's a copy cat answer without opening the original post... which isn't displayed in the review.

Comment: @Lundin these aren't displayed for convenience of reviewers who recommend deletion of blatant non-answers (which have no need to bother checking other answers). Those willing to review as Looks OK would better go out of review tab and double check before casting a vote ([discussed in more details here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314697/165773))

Comment: I thought this was a poor answer, which should be handled with voting. I'm kind of surprised to have been banned for this review. What was the expected course of action?

Comment: @gnat This here is someone who said no action needed on a seemingly ok answer. Yes, veteran reviewers know that the review audits have been hopelessly broken for ages and therefore always view the original post, or otherwise you'll get shot down for doing voluntary work free of charge.

Comment: @giusti You were apparently expected to open the original post in a separate window, read all 9 answers in detail, and in case the one you reviewed appeared to contain code stolen from any existing answer, go back to the review, then flag for moderator attention with a custom reason about plagiarism. If this procedure seems unreasonable to you, then one sensible solution is to boycott reviewing in the future.

Comment: @Lundin it's a known and popular trick among spammers that they copy text from some positive score answer in the same question exactly with purpose to make it look "a seemingly ok answer". Any reviewer, no matter veteran or not should take this into account if they are going to pick Looks OK (nothing like that isn't of course needed for recommending deletion). And if it looks like too much work, well, [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: @gnat I'm fine with using "skip", but are we really expected to review *all* answers?

Comment: @giusti if you are going to pick Looks OK then sure yes, a responsible reviewer would check all answers before doing so (as a side note that's one of the reasons why I almost never pick Looks OK, too much work to check)

Comment: @gnat But this answer doesn't contain any links so it isn't spam. It's just some confused newbie posting an answer instead of commenting on the one that helped them. Because said newbie didn't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: @Lundin yet another known trick by spammers (yes, they adapt to anti-spam measures here) is to either add a link in later edit or make it invisible. The purpose is of course the same as usual, to make it look "a seemingly ok answer"

Comment: How can I find out how long I've been banned for, since the interface didn't tell me anythng?

Comment: This doesn't even show in my review history.

Comment: @gnat We can't reject reviews because "the poster might add a spam link in the future"...

Comment: @Lundin yes, but we can (and should) reject when they plagiarize in the process of preparing this trick

Comment: @gnat That doesn't sound like something that should be handled with manual review at all, but rather something that the site should do automatically.

Comment: @giusti The fact the answer is basically _"This is the only way that works fine with me:"_ followed by an **unattributed** quote should be sufficient warning that something is off and either trigger you to dig deeper or maybe skip. The answer itself is a non-answer, and the quote might be an answer, but you should write your answers yourself, and unattributed quotes are either a license violation or just plagiary.

Comment: What Mark said. And also Mark. I'll admit that I do expect reviewers to be diligent. I could be flippant about this and just say, "I've upped my standards, now up yours," but as I said in my answer, I really only hand out these bans in what I think are obvious cases. I think this one was obvious. It took me about 2 seconds of just looking at the answer to figure it was *probably* a "thanks" answer, and then another 10 sec to confirm. That isn't too much to ask of a reviewer, really. If you haven't developed that intuition yet, then it'll take you longer, or you can contribute in other ways.

Comment: I think it's important to state, you probably cannot review every question with an expert eye. If it's a question or answer outside of my area of expertise, and it's not obvious to me that there are problems with the content, I just skip it, to allow people who know more than me to review it.  I always err on the side of caution, and don't want to condemn, or give something a pass, that I'm unsure about.  There's no harm in skipping something, and it can often be the right thing to do.

Comment: @CodyGray How long did you set the ban?

Comment: @giusti 8 days this time, up from 4 days when you were last automatically banned by the system on September 20th. So, the ban clears tomorrow. You really should be able to see this information. What happens when you visit https://stackoverflow.com/review/?

Comment: @CodyGray I can't believe they haven't made being in a review ban more obvious yet either considering the feature request you linked was based off the question I asked almost 3 years ago now

Comment: I can't believe it, either, @WhatsThePoint. It's almost as if the company has other priorities.

Comment: I'm really surprised to get banned for something seemingly minor. I marked a question as "Requires Editing" instead of "Unsalvagable" because it was a brand-new user & their question showed some merit... I thought we were supposed to be being more welcoming to new users. If it had been one that I marked as "Looks OK" which was clearly unsalvageable then yes... but wow 5 days no triage to do when i get bored at work :\

Comment: I've apparently gotten a 32 day ban for my review on triage/25651645 . I made my mistake on March 20 and my ban expires 20 hours from right now.  Is that typical??  Was this an escalation because I'd been banned 16 days, 8 days, 4 days in the past? If I never knew about those bans how can I see when / what they were? ... I guess if the goal is to get me to stop reviewing, it worked, because there's no way I'm going to do any reviews ever again if someone can seriously ban me for 32 days without any attempt whatsoever to let me know.