# Banned from review queues for 7 days because of an "unhelpful" review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

As someone who has not been at this for a very long time, I find this really dumb. I took my own personal time to try and help make the site better and I am banned from the review queues for a week because a moderator didn't agree with me that a post could have been improved with editing.

I went back and looked at the post in question and the other two reviewers had also marked it as requires editing. There was an actual question in the post, and with some editing, it could have been formatted into a question that would be usable on the site.

I am just having a hard time understanding the review ban. So because a mod disagreed with all of the reviewers and decided they wanted to close the question we are all now banned for a week? This is the first time I have ever had a review marked as unhelpful.

If I have to constantly worry about a mod disagreeing with me and getting me banned, why would I even bother continuing to try and help the community with these reviews?

This is totally backward.

Similar situation [Getting banned from review, although my co-reviewers agree with me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me). I seriously don't understand this.

Comment: [I also](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25328805) [don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25328403) [why you were](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25327652) [banned](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25328709) [/s](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25328403)

Comment: Which review is link in the review ban? Also trying to help doesn't mean you're actually helping. When your reviews are incorrect, then others need to clean those posts up and that isn't helpful.

Comment: Why does this not answer your question? [Getting banned from review, although my co-reviewers agree with me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me) The answer has very detailed explanations as to what's wrong with your current use of "Requires Editing"

Comment: Okay but the general consensus on those questions were that they could be edited to be better. I understand now that the requires editing pushes it to the queue for mods to edit not notify the OP. @leonheess

Comment: That other users also reviewed incorrectly doesn't help/mean much. I would guess that the other reviewers also got review banned.

Comment: I read through the linked post and I an having trouble understanding the ban though. It would be more productive to notify the user that their review was overruled or something. I had no idea until I tried seeing if I could help any more.

Comment: The review *wasn't* overruled. All the people who reviewed it said it required editing, and that was the consensus. The problem is, that consensus was *wrong*. Everyone who reviewed that post, including you, made the wrong choice. Moderators regularly hand out review bans for people who make the wrong decision in the review queues, with the intention of *informing* those reviewers that they made the wrong choice and *educating* them on how to improve.

Answer (score 24):

Sam, there is absolutely no way that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25328403) could be turned into a legitimate Stack Overflow question with edits from normal community members like you or me.

It's entirely possible that there's a good Stack Overflow question hidden in there somewhere, but it's going to need *major* edits to clarify and expand it, and those edits are going to *have* to come from the person who originally asked the question.

In such cases, the "Requires Editing" button is not the correct choice. The "Requires Editing" button should only be used:

> for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing

Note the word "*you*" there in that description.

If *you* cannot edit the question into shape, then you should be choosing the "Unsalvagable" option, and going on to recommend that the question be closed.

You failed to do that in this case. Admittedly, your mistake is a very common one—lots of users misunderstand the meaning of the "Requires Editing" button. That's the purpose of this review ban: to bring your attention to this mistake.

As part of the review ban, you were presented with this message:

> Your review on https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25328403 wasn't helpful. "Requires Editing" should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is unsalvagable and/or can only be improved by the author, please flag/vote to close or delete instead. For more information, see [Getting banned from review, although my co-reviewers agree with me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148).

Comment: Thanks Cody, I understand the reason for the ban. I don't understand why the option is to go straight to a ban though. It seems it would be more helpful for people who are newer to the queue to have the system send notification that their review was overruled. Going straight to ban seems a bit rough and like it would turn people off from wanting to continue.

Comment: @Sam Bans are the only option moderators have in cases like this. They're the only way we can send reviewers a "message", so to speak, regarding their recent reviews. I would also argue that it kinda *does* make sense, as we want to temporarily stop you from doing any more reviews until we can ensure that you've seen our message. On a bigger picture level, I agree that the user experience surrounding the review queues is a bit rough, and definitely needs to be improved. The developers of this site are doing a usability study here, and planning to improve them.

Comment: Remarkable stamina to rescue yet another disappointed SO user, and keep that horrible review queue going, clearly we need a Medal of Honor badge.  Pin.

Comment: I appreciate you being open to discussing this @Cody. I was just very surprised it went straight to a 7 day ban, which I see now is because multiple questions were marked closed. I think another way this could be improved is around the language of flagging and closing. The OP of some of those questions could have tried to improve them. Closing the question seems a bit harsh when the OP could potentially edit it to make it better.

Comment: @HansPassant is it a failure of the new person to reviewing or the site for not making it more clear what the options mean? Everyone has to start somewhere

Comment: @SamG Closure isn't permanent - if a closed question is edited into shape by the OP, it can be reopened. With the recent change to lower the required reopen votes to 3, it isn't even that hard to do. The problem is that 9 times out of 10, the OP never puts in that effort.

Comment: @Sam Yeah, um, the moderator who generally hands out these bans has been jumping straight to 7 days for the first one, which does seem a bit harsh to me, too. I'll have a talk with them. I think the idea is to make the ban long enough to ensure that you will see the message. One of the other UX problems with review is that [ban messages aren't very visible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351377), so that may be why he chose 7 days. Anyway...no, closure of a question is *not* harsh. The point of closure is to give time to edit/improve the question before answers start coming in.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery ah that makes sense. Appreciate your clarification on that.

Cody I agree with you on the visibility. I also look forward to the ban being over so that I can help the community. Was never my intention to add more work to others in the community. Appreciate your discussion around the topic

Comment: Since you've seen the message, I think the review ban has served its purpose. I've therefore lifted it for your account, @Sam. It's worth pointing out that there is [a guide to the Triage review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue) available as a FAQ here on Meta, which might be worth a perusal if you have the time.

Answer (score 13):

Should raise the rep limit for reviewing some of these queues. This is just one of many things not really having any attention paid to it though, and to be honest the remaining responsible people are in over their heads at the moment.

Pretty clear that, like many aspects of this site, the only people who understand how to use this feature are the ones who have been involved in discussing its development. So, while your review was wrong, it isn't really your fault.

"Requires Editing" is a complete misnomer. The system uses this as "an average user can improve this post", but what users read is "in theory this could be edited into a worthwhile question by the asker".

The disconnect there is unfortunate, and unlikely to be changed.

And before you think I am just a bitter meta user, keep this in mind: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287473/. That is a feature request I made to simply change one button in the review interface from 2015. Since then there have probably been thousands of review bans similar to yours. The annoyance is well justified at this point.

[image]

Comment: You may recall [I threw a fit about "Requires Editing" some time back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues). It *did* result in the descriptive text getting changed. I somehow had missed your suggestion reiterated here. In case you are not aware, developers and a designer are currently working to improve the review queues. See [Yaakov's message here in SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48575482#48575482) inviting you to participate.

Comment: @CodyGray - Hm, interesting, I might send an email. To be honest, I have issues feeling motivated to participate with anything corporate related anymore, which is a bummer considering how many times I have interacted with them in the past. Either way, thanks for the link.